# Orthogonality and projection of a vector

Tags: vectors

got two vectors AB = (0,-2,1) and AC = ( 2,-1,0).
I'm supposed to find the unit vector that is orthogonal on both AB and AC.

What i've done is find the "cross-product" AB x AC = [1,2,4]
My unit vector is then $\frac{[1,2,4]}{\sqrt{21}}$ . I got a feeling i've done something wrong here. Please verify that is the correct answer.

I'm also supposed to find the scalarprojection from AC down to AB. I need a hint to get started with that. Thanks

Comment: The great thing about problems in linear algebra is that one can almost always check whether one has gotten the correct answer. If vectors $\textbf{v}_1$ and $\textbf{v}_2$ are orthogonal then $\textbf{v}_1\cdot \textbf{v}_2=0$. The scalar projection of vector $\textbf{a}$ onto vector $\textbf{b}$ is given by $\frac{\textbf{a}\cdot \textbf{b}}{||\textbf{b}||}$ Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the calculation as well...yes your numbers check out OK...

... and the scalar projection you need to do, that is simply the dot product...take the dot product of AC with the unit vector of AB...

Comment: Thanks Tom! 
Is the scalar projection really that simple?

Comment: believe it or not, yes...just don't mix up AB with AC in your calculations and you're good to go! Glad I was able to help--!